# Do JavaScript implementations create a new stack-frame for block-level scopes?

Tags: javascript, scope, stack, closures, stack-frame

I am curious whether JavaScript engines create a new stack-frame, especially when closures are involved.

It seems like this would generally be overkill, since the use-case where it seems beneficial (extremely large functions with a lot of block-level variable declarations) is generally not considered best-practice anyways.

I have provided an example below that I hope illustrates my question well.

```
function getTalkingButton(type) {
    if (type === 1) {
        // block scope, new stack-frame?
        let name = "Thundercat";
        return function() {
            console.log(name);
        };
    }
    else {
        // block scope, new stack-frame?
        let warcry = "Hooooooooo!";
        return function() {
            console.log(warcry);
        }
    }
}

getTalkingButton(1)(); // Thundercat
getTalkingButton(2)(); // Hooooooooo!
```

If the scope of this question is too large, I would just add that I am most curious about the "bigger" players like V8 (Chrome, Node.js) or SpiderMonkey (Firefox).

Comment: I wouldn't assume that JavaScript runtimes use the stack for any sort of scope storage.

Comment: This question seems too broad to be practical to answer. To actually answer this a person would have to account for implementations in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge, IE and NodeJS (at least). Perhaps narrow the scope of the question to a single implementation? Just thought...

Comment: Why does it matter? This is an implementation detail, and could easily vary depending on how a particular function is optimized.

Comment: @jpoveda alright, I'll add a note at the end suggesting specific engines of interest if the scope is too large.

Comment: @Barmar agreed, this was just a question born out of curiosity.

Comment: @AndrewHo - nothing wrong with curiosity! Knowing what's going on under the hood may not be immediately practical, but I think it makes us better developers in the long run. I wish I could be of help beyond helping to narrow your question. :)